# Find the largest caterpillar subtree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, search-algorithms, graph-traversal

I have a problem to solve, but I am having some issues with it...

Find an algorithm with time complexity O(V+E), where V and E stand for vertices and edges respectively. The algorithm searches a tree graph for a subgraph. The subgraph is supposed to be the so called [caterpillar graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CaterpillarGraph.html), i.e. a path with "legs" or "hair" like the one in the picture (the "legs" or "hair" must be of length 1 from the base path).

[image: An example of a caterpillar tree graph.]

What's more, the algorithm has to find a caterpillar subgraph with the highest number of vertices. Could anyone please help me? Also sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you find the largest centipede in a subtree and store it in the root of the subtree?  Then, that root can either be joining to sub-centipedes, or it can be the end of a sub-centipede that can be extended further ...

Answer (score 1):

I will show how to find the size of the largest caterpillar subtree, finding a caterpillar of that size can be done by keeping track of the decisions made in the formulas, similar to dynamic programming.

Select a vertex $r$ as the root of the tree. Let $C(v)$ be the size of the largest caterpillar in the subtree of $v$ such that the stalk of the caterpillar can be extended to include $v$. (in other words: the largest caterpillar such that $v$ is adjacent to an endpoint of the stalk in this caterpillar.)
Because it needs to be possible to extend the stalk, there is at most one subtree of $v$ where the caterpillar for $C(v)$ can have more than one vertex. This gives the following recursive formula for $C(v)$, which we define for all vertices in tree except the root $r$: $$C(v)= \begin{cases} \max_{c\in \mathrm{children}(v)} C(c) + |\mathrm{children}(v)| - 1& \text{if $v$ has at least one child} \\ 1 & \text{if $v$ is a leaf}\end{cases}.$$

The value $C(v)$ can be computed for all vertices in $O(V+E)$ time by traversing the tree from leaf to root. Of course, now we have only considered caterpillars where $v$ is adjacent to the endpoint of a stalk. Given $C(v)$, we can compute the size of the largest caterpillar such that $v$ lies on the stalk and the stalk lies in the subtree of $v$: $$C'(v)=\begin{cases} C(v)&\text{if $v$ has at most one child} \\ \max_{c,c'\in \mathrm{children}(v), c\neq c'} C(c)+C(c') + \mathrm{degree}(v)-2& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}  .$$ Now the maximum value of $C'(v)$ gives the number of